# Web Scraping w/ Scrapy-Splash -- different results for different proxies?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy-splash

I have a list of proxy addresses that I am randomly choosing from and feeding into a `SplashRequest` within a Scrapy spider. To confirm that this was working, I decided to try to scrape the results from [What Is My IP?](https://www.whatismyip.com). As proxies were randomly chosen, I noticed three different responses based on the IP:

1. 502 Bad Gateway
2. 200 OK where the `body` says "Sorry, whatismyip.com is not available because it is categorized as security.nettools."
3. 200 OK with the correct proxy address being returned

If anyone could explain to me what is going on in #1 and #2 that would be much appreciated!

**Edit**

I have a Splash instance in a Docker container, and I am creating a `SplashReqeuest` (not a scrapy request) and feeding it a proxy IP chosen at random. For some IPs, I am able to confirm that it is being passed through to the request (see item 3), so that seems to validate this approach -- the random proxy IP *is* being fed through to the `SplashRequest`. However, for some of the IPs, I get a `502 Bad Gateway` or that weird `200 Ok` where "What Is My IP" doesn't return the IP.

The result are consistent for a given IP address i.e. if address X gives result 1, it always gives result 1.

Comment: Where did you find those proxies? It sounds like you need better ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've only used scrapy-splash a handful of times, but heavily rely on scrapy. My guess is that you're using a splash instance from scrapinghub. I think it's because of the ip that's actually being used to make the request.

One example I have is trying to scrape google shopping. Google traces the ip back to the origin. So regardless of my ip pool being located in the US. Some ips where tracing back to other countries and returning results for that county. 
Say we have the below code.

```
def start_request:
  yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.googleshopping.com/shopping/ID','splash':{})
```

This is going to trigger scrapy to create the request. Even though the request was made on your device it's sending that request to the splash server. Which can live in docker or a splash instance on scraping hub, where ever it may be. That splash instance is going to have it own ip address attached to it, and that ip is what Google will see. Now if you include a proxy in that request, that ip can be from literally anywhere in the world depending on who is hosting it, which would obfuscate the ip even more. Long story short, the request might not be coming from the ip you think it's coming from.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure I understand your example. Would you mind trying to clarify it a bit?

Comment: Edited my answer to the best of my ability lol. Technical explanation is not my strong suit.

Comment: Thanks for your edit! I included more info in my original question to try and make it clearer.

Comment: Based off of your edit, I would say we're about 90% on the same page. When you pass the splash parameter to scrapyRequest, you can provide your splash url and convert it to a splash request. Short answer to all of this though, it's your proxies. Get some paid, reliable US based proxies.

Comment: I accepted your answer, but it's really your above comment that solved it -- "get some paid, reliable US based proxies"